# Programatically copy a content control along with its contents

Tags: controls

Any idea, what should be done if I want to copy a content Control into another, along with its contents. Note: Content control will contain other content controls too. When I copy the content control, I need to copy it along with its contents

Answer (score 0):

[Export the content of content control into another word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610143/export-the-content-of-content-control-into-another-word-document)

perhaps this question answers what you were looking for