# Export the content of content control into another word document

Tags: ms-word, openxml, word-contentcontrol

I have a word document with many content controls. How can I export the content of content control into another word document?
I'm using C# and open xml sdk.
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two great articles that will show you how to do this:

1. [Using LINQ to XML to Retrieve
   Content Controls in Word 2007](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/08/21/using-linq-to-xml-to-retrieve-content-controls-in-word-2007.aspx)
2. [Using Nested Content Controls for
   Data and Content Extraction from
   Open XML WordprocessingML
   Documents](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/03/02/using-nested-content-controls-for-data-and-content-extraction.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

content controls are not bound to CustomXMLParts. I'm using Altchunck to merge multiple docx files into one document. Each docx file is inserted within a content control.The merged document is opened in a winforms application using DSOFramer. I want to update the source docx file when the content control content is modified.
Regards.